# Вводе в консоль "бьются" данные строк и выводится абракадабра вместо заданных слов

Tags: c++, функции, visual-c++, указатели, память

Код усложнён потому что пытался повторить ошибку более сложного проекта (получилось), чтобы было прощё её решить.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

const int a = 50;

class chars {
    char s[a], h[a], * j = 0, *f = 0;
public:
    void set_s(char* b) {
        j = s;
        j = b;
    }
    void set_h(char* n) {
        f = h;
        f = n;
    }
    char *get_s() { 
        return j;
    }
    char* get_h() {
        return f;
    }
};
chars h[2];

void chars_1();
void out();

int main() {
    int d = 5;
    chars_1();
    cin >> d;
    out();

}

void chars_1() {
    char c[a], d[a], * v = 0, *b = 0;
    v = c;
    b = d;
    cin >> v;
    cin >> b;
    h[1].set_s(v);
    h[1].set_h(b);

}

void out() {
    cout << "\n";
    cout << h[1].get_s() << "\n";
    cout << h[1].get_h() << "\n";
}
```

В сегменте

```
int main() {
    int d = 5;
    chars_1();
    cin >> d;
    out();

}
```

Если задействовано cin >> d;, то вывод ломается и выводит вообще не то, что нужно, но если это строку закоментировать, то всё работает, как должно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

До добавления второго массива символов в класс всё работало, как должно вне зависимости от ввода.
Мне кажется, что ошибка связана с выделением памяти для консоли, но не знаю, как это исправить и насколько вообще верно это предположение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работаете с локальными массивами, срок жизни которых — функция...

```
char c[a], d[a], * v = 0, *b = 0;
v = c;
b = d;
cin >> v;
cin >> b;
h[1].set_s(v);
h[1].set_h(b);
```

Вот тут вы записываете `v` и `b` в `h[1]` —

```
void set_s(char* b) {
    j = s;
    j = b;
}
void set_h(char* n) {
    f = h;
    f = n;
}
```

но именно как *указатели* на массивы в функции `chars_1()`. Когда вы из нее вышли, массивы уничтожены, указатели остаются просто на какие-то места в памяти, которые могут быть благополучно переписаны. Типичное UB (неопределенное поведение).

Всё. Ну, а то, что при удалении `cin >> d;` все *кажется* работающим — так это просто потому что в этом случае память случайно оказалась не перезаписанной.

P.S. Кстати, у вас масса каких-то лишних телодвижений с массивами... Например, вот это

```
    j = s;
    j = b;
```

Смысл в первом присваивании? `j` тут же перезаписывается и указывает на `b`.

Создается ощущение, что вы не очень понимаете, как эта вся механика с массивами и указателями работает...

Comment: Аааааааа
Это всё объясняет
Я и правда здесь ощутимо тупанул и забыл, как именно указатели работают, но теперь буду знать 
А странные телодвижения были, чтобы указатель указывал на нужную переменную, а второе, чтобы на этот адрес передать значение. Но теперь я вижу, что во втором присваивании просто присвоил j другой адрес... Видимо, в мой логике была ошибка. 

Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо здесь имеет вид принятого ответа (птичка слева) :)